# Akka Remote connection using Java

Tags: java, scala, configuration, akka

I am new to Akka and am not familiar with Scala at all. I am trying to use the Akka+Java for running a project on multiple machines. I was able to successfully run Akka Java examples locally but when I tried to run any of them on two machine, the code stops working. I've looked at the Akka-Sample-Remote source code as well. It also works on a single machine but breaks when used on more than one machine. I think the problem is with the way I set the configurations. I have summarized the problem into a simple HelloWorld problem as below.

There code is divided into two projects with two separate configuration files: a Hello Actor project and a World Actor project. World Actor waits for receiving the Hello Message from the Hello Actor and then prints out the "Hello World". Here below you can see the code and the configuration for these two projects. As you can see, the World Actor is started on port 1719 and the Hello Actor starts on port 1720 and tries to connect to the World Actor using "akka.tcp://WorldApplication@192.27.336.187:1719/user/WorldActor" . Any idea on what is wrong with he code/configuration?

JWorld.java:

```
public class JWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JWorldApplication app = new JWorldApplication();
    System.out.println("Started World Application - waiting for Hello message");
  }

}
```

JWorldApplication.java:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;

import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class JWorldApplication {
  private ActorSystem system;

  public JWorldApplication() {
    system = ActorSystem.create("WorldApplication", ConfigFactory.load()
        .getConfig("WorldConfig"));
    ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(new Props(JWorldActor.class),
        "WorldActor");
  }
}
```

JWolrdActor.java:

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;


public class JWorldActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) {

        if (message instanceof HelloMessage) {
            HelloMessage recMsg = (HelloMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Received Message: " + recMsg.getText());
            System.out.println("***** Hello World! ******" );
        } else {
            System.out.println("UnHandled Message Received" );
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }

}
```

HelloMessage.java:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef; 

public class HelloMessage{
    private ActorRef receiver;
    private String text;
    HelloMessage() {}
    HelloMessage(ActorRef receiver){ this.receiver = receiver;}
    public ActorRef getReceiver(){ return receiver;}
    public void setText(String text) { this.text = text;}
    public String getText() {return text;}
}
```

Application.conf:

```
WorldConfig {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    netty.tcp {
      hostname="192.27.336.187"
      port=1719
    }
  }
}
```

JHello.java:

```
public class JHello {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JHelloApplication testApp = new JHelloApplication();
    System.out.println("Started Hello Application - Sending Hello Message");
    testApp.sayHello();


}
}
```

JHelloApplication.java:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class JHelloApplication {
    private ActorSystem system;
    private ActorRef remoteActor, myActor;

    public JHelloApplication() {
        system = ActorSystem.create("HelloApplication", ConfigFactory.load()
                .getConfig("HelloConfig"));
        myActor = system.actorOf(new Props(JHelloActor.class),"HelloActor");
        remoteActor = system
                .actorFor("akka.tcp://WorldApplication@192.27.336.187:1719/user/WorldActor");
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        myActor.tell(new HelloMessage(remoteActor));
    }

}
```

JHelloActor.java:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class JHelloActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) {
        if (message instanceof HelloMessage) {
            HelloMessage msg = (HelloMessage) message;
            if (msg.getReceiver() !=null){
                msg.setText("Hello");
                msg.getReceiver().tell(msg, getSelf());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("UnHandled Message Received" );
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }

}
```

application.conf:

```
HelloConfig {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    netty.tcp {
      hostname="192.27.336.187"
      port=1720
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this was answered in the akka mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/1tLBTZdo8tA/bhCqkilFlxcJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Patrcik the question is finally answered by Patrik on Akka groups. The problem was that the Akka{} tag is missing in both configuration files. Adding this tag solves the problem.